# How can i plot 2 boxplot with diferent files? Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

So, im trying to plot two diferent box plot with diferent files, here my code:

```
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid 0.5
set xlabel ""
set ylabel "Boxplot Value"
set grid layerdefault
set xtics ("Data A" 1, "Data B" 2)
set xtics rotate by -50
plot "out4.txt" using (1):1 notitle with boxplot, "out20.txt" using (1):2 notitle with boxplot
```

And this error shows up: *"boxplot.gnu", line 8: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points*

My data is arranged like this:

> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7
>
> 6
>
> 23
>
> 423
>
> 42
>
> 342
>
> 34
>
> 234

Just one column, its the same data in both files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file `"out20.txt"` also consists of only one column, what should gnuplot plot if you write  `"out20.txt" using (1):2`? There is no second column to plot. That's what gnuplot is telling you "Skipping data file with no valid points".

If `"out4.txt"` corresponds to `Data A` at `x=1` and `"out20.txt"` to `Data B` at `x=2`, then changing line 8 to the following should show your graph:

```
plot "out4.txt" using (1):1 notitle with boxplot, "out20.txt" using (2):1 notitle with boxplot
```